# Глубокое клонирование поля типа List<Класс> в Java

Tags: java, переопределение

При переопределении функции clone(), если класс имеет поле-ссылку, то необходимо провести глубокое клонирование.

```
@Override
public Employee clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    Employee e = (Employee)super.clone();
    e.hireDay = (Date)hireDay.clone();
    return e;
}
```

В случае, если это ссылка на список:

```
 class Класс {
 List<Класс2> list;
 }
```

Переопределение делается:

```
 Класс e = (Класс)super.clone();
 for(int i = 0; i<e.list.size(); i++){
 e.list.get(i).clone(); 
 } 
 return e;
```

Правильно ли это?

Comment: Пробовали так делать? Что получилось?

Comment: Нет, не правильно. То что вы сделали, это просто создали новый список с теми же объектами. Вам нужно явно пройтись по списку и на каждом объекте вызвать clone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Операция `clone` создаст новый объект с теми же ссылками на те же объекты. Если вы хотите чтобы в списке были копии объектов, нужно явно это реализовать. Т.е. написать следующее:

```
class B implements Cloneable {
   @Override
   protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      return super.clone();
   }
}

class A implements Cloneable {
    private List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
       A clone = (A) super.clone();
       clone.list = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
       for (B b : list)
           clone.list.add((B) b.clone());

       return clone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) не реализует `Cloneable` соответственно вызвать `clone` через переменную/поле типа `List<T>` не получится.

Есть реализации `List` которые переопределяют `clone`, например, ArrayList и LinkedList, но они не выполняют глубокого копирования списка. Т.е. они создают новый список, который содержит те же элементы.

Из документации [ArrayList.clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone--)

> Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)

Для глубокого копирования списка нужно пройтись по всем элементам и клонировать каждый.

Например, так:

```
e.list = new ArrayList<Класс2>(list.size());
for (Класс2 item : list) e.list.add(item.clone());
```

Похожий вопрос в английской версии: [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)